# CoreData: How to Insert an Object into CoreData data structure?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on an iOS application. I had already written some code in AppDelegate.swift, but then realized that I need to use CoreData data structure. I integrated it into my code using this tutorial: (https://welcm.uk/blog/adding-core-data-to-an-existing-project-in-xcode-10-swift-4).

I went into the my-model-name.xcdatamodeld file and made my entity (it has TWO string attributes).

In my AppDelegate file, in didReceiveRemoteNotification, I have added a new entity object into the CoreData data structure, like so:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
       //omitted code to obtain information to store in atributes


        let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newUser = Info(context: managedContext)
        newUser.title = title
        newUser.body = body
        
    }
```

... where 'title' and 'body' are string variables.

Now, how do I check if that object is correctly stored inside CoreData?

**EDIT**

I have added `try managedContext.save()` to my code. I have another issue; I am trying to print out all of the entities stored in CoreData in my ContentView.swift. Here is my code to do that:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Info.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: []
    ) var languages: FetchedResults<Info>
    
    var body: some View {
        List(languages, id: \.self) { language in
            Text(language.title ?? "Unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

In the line `List(languages, id: \.self) { language in`, I am getting an error that reads "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x19d012818)." I can't figure out why this is happening. Any tips?

Comment: It won't be stored until you call `save` on the managed object context.  You can fetch objects using an `NSFetchRequest`

Comment: Save context after add, update, detele. Add this line **do { try managedContext.save() } catch { }**

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `managedContext.save()` to save it to the coreData. I have updated the code below.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   //omitted code to obtain information to store in atributes


    let managedContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newUser = Info(context: managedContext)
    newUser.title = title
    newUser.body = body
    // a try catch block for error handling.
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch {
        print("Could not save.", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. Now, in ContextView.swift, I am trying to print out all of the entities stored in CoreData in a "list view." 

I have updated my original post to include this problem. Please take a look.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth thats a different question. Please accept this answer and add a new question. Please share the link here and I will be happy to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

After any updates, Save manage object context commits all the current changes to the context's parent store.
In your case, Just call "saveContext" method which is already available on your AppDelegate.swift.

```
    /* Do your Operation like Create, Update or delete*/

    self.saveContext()
```

Comment: I have added this. Now, in ContextView.swift, I am trying to print out all of the entities stored in CoreData in a "list view." I have updated my original post to include this problem. Please take a look. –